# How to delete a specific element from an component array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When my code executes to remove an element, the last array element gets deleted, not the specific index I am referring to in the code.

Any assistance in reviewing this would be helpful.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        rows: []
    }
    this.addHandler = this.addHandler.bind(this);
    this.removeHandler = this.removeHandler.bind(this);
}
addHandler(event){
    const rows = this.state.rows.concat(<Component>);
    this.setState({
                    rows
    })
}

removeHandler(id){
    const index = id;
    this.setState({
        row: this.state.row.filter( (x, i) => i !== index) 

    })
}

render () {
    const rows = this.state.rows.map((Element, index) => {
        return <Element key={index} id={index} index={index} func1= 
        {this.addHandler} func2={this.removeHandler} />
    });
    // func2 gets called by child
    return (
            <div className="rows">

                <button onClick={this.addHandler} >+</button>

                {rows}
             </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your problem may lie in using index as the key of the mapping. Doing so and then changing the number of elements of the array [might create problems](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: That is exactly what the problem was. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use index as a key for mapping out an array. Check out this package, easy to use and get the job done [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: That was the problem. I appreciate the help.